# Why the okhttp3.CookieJar interface states, 'A reasonable policy is to reject all cookies'

Tags: cookiejar

> Provides policy and persistence for HTTP cookies.
> As policy, implementations of this interface are responsible for selecting which cookies to accept and which to reject. A reasonable policy is to reject all cookies, though that may interfere with session-based authentication schemes that require cookies.
> As persistence, implementations of this interface must also provide storage of cookies. Simple implementations may store cookies in memory; sophisticated ones may use the file system or database to hold accepted cookies. The rfc_6265_53 specifies policies for updating and expiring cookies.
> What issues might arise if not rejecting all cookies?

I tried managing the cookies by myself but didn't encounter any issues.